# dual-password-like feature for MySQL before v 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, aws, password

**tldr;** Is there a dual-password-like feature for MySQL v.5.x ?

### Problem

I have a MySQL server that needs to **temporarily allow two passwords for one account**, due to legal constraints that impose DBMS service accounts to periodically change password.

I don't think I can *just change* service account pw because there would be *some (albeit little) time gap*
between **DBMS pw change** and **DB access information on server-side code** that needs to be deployed when changed.

I understand there is a dual-password feature that allows primary/secondary pw,
but the feature is from v 8.0 to which I cannot upgrade.

I am under following constraints & environments:

- cannot add more accounts (ex. adding *user* accounts that change pw and fixing *admin* account's pw)
- cannot update MySQL version (current version: 5.7.12)
- DB is hosted on AWS RDS
- DB access information on server-side code is retrieved from AWS parameter store

I am aware of AWS CLI/API that requests change in AWS RDS and AWS parameter store respectively, yet the time-gap problem still remains.

### Question

1. Is there an old version equivalent of dual-password? Or is there a way to manually implement it?
2. Alternatively, is there an AWS feature that could safely sync aws parameter store change and aws rds pw change?
3. Finally, does the pw change in DBMS immediately/forcefully disconnect existing connection pool for re-authorization? or does it only apply to new connections? is there an option for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dual-password feature in MySQL 5.x.

At my last job, we used MySQL 5.x, and authentication was done using SSL certificates instead of passwords. The authentication was satisfied if the certificate had an `ISSUER` property indicating it was created by the certificate authority owned by the company we worked for. But the certificate itself had an expiration date, so we had to update it periodically and redeploy the certificate to the client application.

As long as the same `ISSUER` was used for the certificate, either the old or new certificate would authenticate a user. So you could generate a new certificate and deploy it with the application anytime you want (before the old one expired). There was no downtime required.

This solution works for your needs, but it would require you set up a certificate authority (CA) for your company so you can generate secure certificates.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html#create-user-tls for reference on using SSL/TLS options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your first-hand experience and the reference doc. will look into authentication via SSL certificate